# NodeJS and multiple mini programs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cloud, multiple-projects

I know that this question is going to slightly broad and it is a development theory question.

But I have a client who wants the ability for one nodejs application to be able to host multiple mini programs inside of it using the same structure as the parent nodejs. Without giving too much away, the theory is there is one platform and experimenters could post their experiments and run those experiments within the application in the form of modules. Sorta like cloud9 in theory but with experiments. I will be using shortcodes within the application as room name for socket.io to have the ability to chat within an experiment.

Does anybody have an ideas or could point me to a place where there is something for this?  (I will clarify any questions you may have about this project in the comments.)

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: An Express router can be used like a mini-application, serving a specific set of routes within the domain.